Filter from many json data
I have a component with a grid that displays the names of people. When I click on a row, I navigate to another component that includes the person’s name and additional data.
My goal is to create cards that showcase all the projects associated with a specific person, along with the project names. I’m sourcing all the information from a JSON file acting as my database. Here’s an example of the database structure:
"collaborateurs": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "lastName": "Rami",
      "firstName": "Romain",
      "team": ".NET",
      "dateStart": "2021-01-01",
      "dateEnd": "2021-01-05",
      "project": 5,
      "TOG": 40,
      "dayLeft": -5
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "firstName": "John",
      "team": "Frontend",
      "dateStart": "2022-03-15",
      "dateEnd": "2022-08-31",
      "project": 3,
      "TOG": 20,
      "dayLeft": 10
    }
],
"project": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "client": "Client A",
      "project": "Projet 1",
      "type": "Type A",
      "status": "En cours",
      "dayHuman": "5",
      "team": ".Net",
      "dateStart": "2024-01-01",
      "dateEnd": "2024-12-31"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "client": "Client B",
      "project": "Projet 2",
      "type": "Type B",
      "status": "Terminé",
      "dayHuman": "10",
      "team": ".Net",
      "dateStart": "2024-02-01",
      "dateEnd": "2024-11-30"
    }
],
  "teams": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "teamName": ".Net",
      "collabId": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
      ],
      "projectId": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "5"
      ]
    }
]

In this specific scenario, I want to retrieve all the projects associated with Rami. To achieve this, I need to determine the team Rami is working with, find the projects related to that team, and finally return the names of the clients associated with those projects.
This is how i take and use my data :
export class CollabDetailsComponent {
    route: ActivatedRoute = inject(ActivatedRoute);
    appService = inject(AppService);
    iCollab: ICollab | undefined;
    iProject: IProject[] = [];

    projectList: IProject[] = [];

    iTeams: ITeams[] = [];

    constructor() {
        const icollabId = Number(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);

        this.appService.getCollabById(icollabId).then((collab) => {
            this.iCollab = collab;
        });

        this.appService.getAllProject().then((projectList: IProject[]) => {
            this.projectList = projectList;
        });

        this.appService.getAllTeams().then((teamList: ITeams[]) => {
            this.iTeams = teamList;
        });
    }
}

Currently, I'm able to display all relevant data for the individuals I've selected. However, I encounter difficulties when trying to display their projects, as the project data resides in a separate database.
I've attempted numerous solutions, including:
<ng-container *ngFor="let iProject of projectList">
    <div class="card" *ngIf="iTeams && iTeams[0]?.teamName == iProject?.team">
        <h3>{{ iProject?.client }}</h3>
        <p>{{ iTeams[0].collab }}</p>
    </div>
</ng-container>

<div class="card" *ngFor="let iProject of projectList; where: iCollab?.lastName == iTeams?.collab; and: iTeams?.teamName == iProject?.team">
    <h3>{{ iProject.client }}</h3>
    <p>{{ iProject.project }}</p>
</div>

...and many more, but none have yielded the desired result. The options available either display all projects in the database, leave me with empty cards or nothing.
I believe the root of the problem might be the data structure, as the names of the people and their projects are in array.
How can I resolve this?

You can create a map for teams and users combined like below. So you can check whether a specific user is present in specific team or not.
public teamUsersMap = {};
....
constructor(){
    for(let i=0;i<this.iTeams.length;i++){
        const team = this.iTeams[i];
 
        // Add Team to map if not present
        if(!this.teamUsersMap[team.teamName])
            this.teamUsersMap[team.teamName] = {};
    
        for(let j=0;j<this.iTeams[i].collabId.length;j++){
            const collabId = this.iTeams[i].collabId[j];
        
            // Add User to team map if not present
            if(!this.teamUsersMap[team.teamName][collabId])
                this.teamUsersMap[team.teamName][collabId] = 1;
        }
    }
}

Now in your html you can check as below
<div class="card" *ngFor="let p of projectList;">
    // below id is Rami's id
    <ng-container *ngIf="teamUsersMap[p.team][id]">
        <h3>{{ iProject.client }}</h3>
        <p>{{ iProject.project }}</p>
    </ng-container>
</div>

By formatting and storing data like this in initial phase, you can avoid extra loops and improve performance.

Hi, thanks for your answer, i have some error in the constructor.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-k1rwhr?file=src%2Fexample.ts
i make this little stackblitz only to show the error i have and what i have tried.

I still have the error : Type 'ICollab' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)
for this line :
(error is on both of the 'collabId')
if (!this.teamUsersMap[team.teamName][collabId]) this.teamUsersMap[team.teamName][collabId] = 1; 
i tried to change things in my appService and my class in order to have the good type but nothing works

Is the data same as you mentioned in the question?

Yes, but it looks like he can’t find it. I changed it to
if (!this.teamUsersMap[team.teamName][collabId.toString()]) this.teamUsersMap[team.teamName][collabId.toString()] = 1; 
There are no more errors, but the cards on the page are still empty.

Reproduce your error in stackblitz, I will look into it

https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/LanriusS/AngularPCP
this is my application with only the collab page to see the issue, thanks a lot

can you cross check the link, it says unauthorized

https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/LanriusS/stackblitz
This one should work, the only issue is the json-server not working on stackblitz so i will try to make it local in order to test.
